# How to toggle showing line numbers in vim using a single key press?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I have the following entries which allow me to turn the line numbers on/off with simple key presses

```
nmap <F11> :se nonu<CR>
nmap <F12> :se nu<CR>
```

Is it possible to instead have a single key for the purpose and toggle the behaviour instead of using two keys?

for example something logically like

```
F12:
if nu == 0
  se nu
else
  se nonu
endif
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of prefixing a boolean option with "no", you can prefix it with "inv" to toggle the option.  So:

```
:nmap <F12> :set invnumber<CR>
```

See `:help :set-inv`

Comment: +1 My `vim` (version 7.2) doesn't have that help. I can do `:help set` to see the information, though.

Comment: You should also be able to do `:nmap <F12> :set number!<CR>` with an exclamation at the end for toggling.